# Black screen installing Ubuntu 16.04. How to fix?

Tags: video

The PC is an HP Pavillion 500-164 desktop running windows 10. Trying to install ubuntu and it will not work. Display goes to sleep when i hit "Install Ubuntu". It is plugged in via VGA (only display monitor has.) Secure boot/ fast boot is off and legacy boot is on. I am trying to install via USB. That is the only way I can install as far as I know. I have tried different boot orders but none of them have worked.

Comment: If the computer came with Windows 8 or 10, Windows is going to be installed in EFI mode. Unless you're trying to replace WIndows, Ubuntu needs to be installed in EFI mode as well.

Comment: What graphics card do you have

Answer (score 1):

I have had this occur two times: once on a headless device (Axiontek NA-330) and once on a "regular" server (SuperMicro). In both cases, I was able to `ssh` to the system (hope you added `sshd` to the initial install). I have reported this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1611921) but no action has been taken.

The solution I have found is as follows:

```
systemctl enable console-getty.service
systemctl start console-getty.service
```

or, if it's a serial console

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service (modify if your tty isn't 0)
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

If using minicom you may need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get a response.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to install ubuntu 16.04 on my new Dell XPS 15 9560 laptop alongside windows 10. I resolved the issue by placing the linux bootloader on the same partition as the windows bootloader: Installation type > Something else > Device for bootloader location > /dev/xxxp1 not the top level /dev/xxx.